# Point in SQL statement

Tags: sql, excel, oledb

I have to pull a list of data from an Excel sheet which has a point in the column header. If I remove the point everything works perfectly, but if I keep the point then I get an error message.

Working: `SELECT DISTINCT Ty FROM dbStock`

Not working: `SELECT DISTINCT Ty. FROM dbStock`

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error (missing
>   operator) in query expression 'Ty.'.

I searched on the internet, but couldn't find anything about this.
I tried to place `Ty.` between `''`, `""` and `[]`, but no luck.

Any idea?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is this what you need?

"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Projects\Rework Template.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";"

Comment: So why don't you use version 1 - as it works? Or do you want `Ty.` as column header, instead of `Ty`?

Comment: These points / column headers are being automatically pushed by another system, and they can't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT2: Just to put this into the answer (from comments)

The solution was to try a `SELECT * FROM ...`. This brought up, that the column's name was translated to `Ty#`. The OP could continue with this name...

#### previous

From this

```
Working: SELECT DISTINCT Ty FROM dbStock
Not working: SELECT DISTINCT Ty. FROM dbStock
```

I take, that the column's name is `Ty` actually. The point let's the engine think, that this is a multipart qualifier (like `tablename.columnname`).

You might use

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ty AS [Ty.] FROM dbStock
```

If you need the point in the output column name...

#### EDIT: Just to have mentioned it:

SQL-Server can deal with this...

```
declare @tbl TABLE([Ty.] INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1),(2),(3);

SELECT * FROM @tbl
SELECT [Ty.] FROM @tbl
```

Comment: Thanks, this is starting to make sense, but I'm not quite there:
The columnname is Ty.
If I use: SELECT DISTINCT Ty AS [Ty.] FROM dbStockcode
Then I get an error message: Invalid bracketing of name 'Ty.'.  
If I use this the other way around: SELECT DISTINCT [Ty.] AS Ty FROM dbStock
I get also an error message, now complaining that the statement is empty... System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): '' is not a valid name.

Comment: @GertDeWilde, edited my answer (yet no solution...) What would be interesting is: How is the column named if you state a simple `SELECT * FROM ...` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It got translated into "Ty#"

I now replaced my query to: SELECT DISTINCT [Ty#] FROM dbStock and it worked!  Don't know why the . gets translated to #, but I'm glad to have it working.

Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, I did selected your post as the answer and voted up your comment, but I forgot to vote it up as well.

Thanks again, you really helped me out here!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Ty.]
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Ty." // In this case, check if QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is set to ON.
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post, I tried those, but these aren't working.
"SELECT DISTINCT [Ty.] FROM dbStock" resulted in an error message saying that the select statement was empty.

"SELECT DISTINCT ""[Ty.]"" FROM dbStock" results in just "Ty." in my list.

Comment: Using [] should work, check this http://venkattechnicalblog.blogspot.in/2009/10/special-symbols-in-column-names-in-sql.html

Comment: Also, when you use `"`, check if `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` option is set to ON.

Comment: If I use that, it will tell me that my statement is empty and I get the message:
"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): '' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.